# Anomalize error: no date or datetime column found

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have some data:

```
   dput(y)
structure(list(date = structure(c(1508803200, 1515456000, 1506384000, 
1501027200, 1503964800, 1517356800, 1519776000, 1511740800, 1511827200, 
1498521600, 1509408000, 1522627200, 1493078400, 1502064000, 1504051200, 
1504569600, 1504742400, 1512432000, 1515628800, 1520467200, 1493164800, 
1496102400, 1496620800, 1501459200, 1506988800, 1508889600, 1512864000, 
1515542400, 1515974400, 1517443200, 1520553600, 1520812800, 1494806400, 
1495756800, 1496188800, 1496707200, 1498608000, 1499040000, 1499299200, 
1501113600, 1501200000, 1502150400, 1504656000, 1507075200, 1508976000, 
1509235200, 1509494400, 1515369600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1517961600, 
1518393600, 1519689600, 1522368000, 1522540800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), word = c("hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", 
"hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", 
"hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", 
"hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", 
"hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", 
"hr", "hr", "hr", "hr"), n = c(22L, 16L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
)), row.names = c(NA, -55L), vars = "date", drop = TRUE, class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("date", "word", "n"
), indices = list(12L, 20L, 32L, 33L, 21L, 34L, 22L, 35L, 9L, 
    36L, 37L, 38L, 3L, 39L, 40L, 23L, 13L, 41L, 4L, 14L, 15L, 
    42L, 16L, 2L, 24L, 43L, 0L, 25L, 44L, 45L, 10L, 46L, 7L, 
    8L, 17L, 26L, 47L, 1L, 27L, 18L, 28L, 48L, 49L, 5L, 29L, 
    50L, 51L, 52L, 6L, 19L, 30L, 31L, 53L, 54L, 11L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(1493078400, 1493164800, 1494806400, 1495756800, 
    1496102400, 1496188800, 1496620800, 1496707200, 1498521600, 
    1498608000, 1499040000, 1499299200, 1501027200, 1501113600, 
    1501200000, 1501459200, 1502064000, 1502150400, 1503964800, 
    1504051200, 1504569600, 1504656000, 1504742400, 1506384000, 
    1506988800, 1507075200, 1508803200, 1508889600, 1508976000, 
    1509235200, 1509408000, 1509494400, 1511740800, 1511827200, 
    1512432000, 1512864000, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 
    1515628800, 1515974400, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1517356800, 
    1517443200, 1517961600, 1518393600, 1519689600, 1519776000, 
    1520467200, 1520553600, 1520812800, 1522368000, 1522540800, 
    1522627200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-55L), vars = "date", drop = TRUE, class = "data.frame", .Names = "date"))
```

and code:

```
y = y %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word,comments) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  count(word,sort = T) 


  y %>% time_decompose(count,method='stl')%>%
    anomalize(remainder,method = 'iqr') %>%
    time_recompose()%>% plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = T,ncol=5,alpha_dots = 0.25)
```

except that I keep getting the following error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :  Evaluation error: Error in prep_tbl_time(): No date or datetime column found..

I followed the github tutorial for this and my columns and types match up to the example. But for some reason, it can't find the column date.

Comment: Which [line causes the error](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)? Can you `dput(head(y))` the beginning of your dataframe so we can [check where the error occurs for ourselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Your syntax also suggests that the printed `y` is after some processing has been done, and is not the original dataframe from before the pipe starts (see the use of `rename` in line 1 which indicates that the original data has column `surveyDate` rather than `date`.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that first section? It's happening in there, but I can't pin it down.

Comment: I had this issue recently, caused by an older version of anomalize installed from Github. Reinstallation of the latest version from CRAN (along with dependencies) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stumper. I worked through that tutorial a few weeks ago, so I'm comparing your data to the `tidyverse_cran_downloads` and I don't see what the difference is. It might not like date as class `POSIX` at any time, but I really don't see how that could matter. I also ran through it with made up data in your same layout and it worked. Hopefully this helps in some way.

```
counts <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2013-09-13", "2014-01-23", "2014-06-24", "2017-04-25", "2017-04-26", "2017-06-28", "2017-09-26")), word = c("hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr", "hr"), count = c(2, 6, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

counts <- counts %>% 
tibbletime::as_tbl_time(index = date)

counts %>% 
time_decompose(count, method = "stl") %>% 
anomalize(remainder) %>% 
time_recompose() %>% 
plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and in my case `group_by` before `time_decompose` helped:

```
y %>% group_by(word) %>%
    time_decompose(count,method='stl')%>%
    anomalize(remainder,method = 'iqr') %>%
    time_recompose()%>% plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = T,ncol=5,alpha_dots = 0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two steps which helped in my case. Think the latter one is more important.

1. Rename date column to index.
2. Removing older version of 'rlang' and updating it.